# Run R script in python using data from python in the R script (rpy2)

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I want to run an R script in python using **rpy2**, I already know how to do this

The R code is:

```
dataR = data.frame( Ingresos = c(23,45,24,23,54),
                    Bonos = c(23,45,12,67,54),
                    Deuda = c(23,4,1,6,3),
                    row.names = c("Nathy", "Tomas", "Joe", "Emily", "Javi") )
dataR
promedio_ingresos = mean(dataR$Ingresos)
Max_Ing = sort(dataR$Ingresos[dataR$Ingresos>promedio_ingresos])
Max_Ing
```

To run this R script in python I use:

```
import rpy2
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r = robjects.r
output = r.source("R_script_run_in_python.R")
output
```

And output gets the last value from my R code

Now I want to run the same code, but using a data that I define in python, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(5,3), 
                   columns = ["Ingresos","Bonos","Deuda"], 
                   index = ["Max", "Nathy", "Tom", "Joe", "Kathy"] )
```

So the R code I want tu run now is just:

```
promedio_ingresos = mean(dataR$Ingresos)
Max_Ing = sort(dataR$Ingresos[dataR$Ingresos>promedio_ingresos])
Max_Ing
```

But dataR being df, how can I do that?

Comment: Curious why do you need to run in R what can easily be run in pandas? Usually `rpy2` is used for specialized modules/libraries available in one and not the other.

Comment: @Parfait I have some code in R and python, now we are migrating all to python, but there are really nice libraries and code developed in R that I want to take advange, for example the scorecard library from R. Also I would not expend to much time migrating some code from R to python

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked

```
# Data    
# Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame( np.random.randn(5,3),
                   columns = ["Ingresos","Bonos","Deuda"],
                   index = ["Max", "Nathy", "Tom", "Joe", "Kathy"] )   
# rpy2 datframe
dataR = pandas2ri.py2ri(df)

# R code
robjects.globalenv["dataR"] = dataR
robjects.r('''
           promedio_ingresos = mean(dataR$Ingresos)
           Max_Ing = sort(dataR$Ingresos[dataR$Ingresos>promedio_ingresos])
''')
print(robjects.globalenv["dataR"])
print(robjects.globalenv["promedio_ingresos"])
print(robjects.globalenv["Max_Ing"])
```